# Azure server node type

Tags: networking, azure

I noticed from *ipconfig* check that some Azure servers that I managed have **node type** ***Peer-Peer***, while some others have **node type** ***Hybrid***.
What is the effect of node types to the Azure server? Specifically, which node type is better?
Furthermore, should the node type be changed, how to change it?

Comment: http://www.tech-faq.com/netbios-node-types.html

Answer (score 0):

As @joeqwerty has mentioned in the comment, this attribute is not related to Azure. If you check it on the on-premises Windows based computer, you will find that this attribute exists too.

What method is used to resolve computer names to IP addresses depends on the configuration of this attribute.

> Name Resolution Methods
>
> Once a client establishes a session with a WINS server, the client can
>   request name resolution services. What method is used to resolve
>   computer names to IP addresses depends on how the network is
>   configured. Four name resolution methods are available:
>
> • B-node (broadcast node) Uses broadcast messages to resolve computer
>   names to IP addresses. Computers that need to resolve a name broadcast
>   a message to every host on the local network, requesting the IP
>   address for a computer name.
>
> • P-node (point-to-point node) Uses WINS servers to resolve computer
>   names to IP addresses. As explained earlier, client sessions have
>   three parts: name registration, name renewal, and name release. When a
>   client needs to resolve a computer name to an IP address, the client
>   sends a query message to the server and the server responds with an
>   answer.
>
> • M-node (modified node) Combines b-node and p-node. With it, a WINS
>   client first tries to use b-node for name resolution. If the attempt
>   fails, the client then tries to use p-node. Because b-node is used
>   first, this method has the same problems with network bandwidth usage
>   as b-node.
>
> • H-node (hybrid node) Also combines b-node and p-node. With it, a
>   WINS client first tries to use p-node for point-to-point name
>   resolution. If the attempt fails, the client then tries to use
>   broadcast messages with b-node. Because point-to-point is the primary
>   method, h-node offers the best performance on most networks. H-node is
>   also the default method for WINS name resolution.